# Why are $T$'s different?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, textbook-erratum

Consider two masses $m_1,m_2$ suspended by a system of pulleys and wires, with negligible masses, according to the folowing figure:

> [image]

The book I'm reading says that the equation of movement of $m_1,m_2$ is:

$$T-m_1 g = m_1 a \quad \quad \quad \quad 2T-m_2 g=\cfrac{-m_2a}{2}$$

I solved each equation for both $a,T$ (following the book instructions) and hence:

$$T=a m_1+g m_1\quad \quad \quad \quad a=\frac{T-g m_1}{m_1}$$

$$T=\frac{1}{4} \left(2 g m_2-a m_2\right)\quad \quad \quad \quad a=-\frac{2 \left(2 T-g m_2\right)}{m_2}$$

Now, by reflexivity:

$$a m_1+g m_1=\frac{1}{4} \left(2 g m_2-a m_2\right) \quad \quad \quad \quad \frac{T-g m_1}{m_1} = -\frac{2 \left(2 T-g m_2\right)}{m_2} $$

And solving for $a,T$, gives me:

$$a=\frac{2  \left(m_2-2 m_1\right)}{4 m_1+m_2}g\quad \quad \quad \quad T=\frac{3  m_1 m_2}{4 m_1+m_2} g$$
But the book says that solving both equations for $a,T$, we have:

$$a=\cfrac{2(m_2 -2m_1)}{4m_1 + m_2}g \quad \quad \quad \quad T=\cfrac{3m_1-2m_2}{4m_1+m_2 }g$$

Now $a$ is what it should be. But why different T's? What did I do wrong?

**Note:** The result I gave is computer verified in Mathematica, I have also made it by hand several times. If it is helpful, here is the code I used:

```
Solve[Solve[T - Subscript[m, 1] g == Subscript[m, 1] a, 
     T][[1]][[1]][[2]] == 
 Solve[2 T - Subscript[m, 2] g == (-Subscript[m, 2] a)/2, 
     T][[1]][[1]][[2]], a][[1]][[1]][[2]]

Solve[Solve[T - Subscript[m, 1] g == Subscript[m, 1] a, 
         a][[1]][[1]][[2]] == 
     Solve[2 T - Subscript[m, 2] g == (-Subscript[m, 2] a)/2, 
         a][[1]][[1]][[2]], T][[1]][[1]][[2]]
```

Comment: -1. Not useful to the community. ... Unless perhaps they happen to be using the same (unidentified) textbook and don't have much confidence in their own powers of calculation or observation.

Comment: @sammygerbil You can downvote according to any moral reasons you want, there is no _system of downvoting legitimation on SE_.  But my question is on topic [according to the help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Maybe it could fit the  _"do my homework"_ category, but as it stands here, my homework is **done.** As I am not from physics, I guessed that there could be some assumption in physics which I was unaware of. As for being _"useful for the community,"_ it's probably some long discussion in the meta which I won't fully agree and probably can't argue about it.

Comment: There is no obligation on you to use this site. If you do use it you have to accept the way that it works. The voting system is used in part to distinguish questions which are well researched and useful to the broad community of users from those which are not. The essence of your question is an error in your textbook. I do not think that is useful to the community. There is no moral reason, and nothing personal, it is purely a matter of whether those who study your question and its answers will learn something useful about physics. Not everyone who down-votes gives a reason. I do.

Comment: @sammygerbil What I said is exactly that I accept the way it works (accept $\neq$ agree) and that you do not have to justify yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The one thing that's certain without any calculation is that your book's expression for the force $T$ makes no sense: It clearly has dimensions of an acceleration, not a force. Your own expression is at least dimensionally consistent. If you add $g$ to the acceleration you have found and multiply the result by $m_1$ you find $T$. To me it looks like (just eye-balling it) the expression you have found.

Answer (score 1):

I used your two equations on top, solving the left one for **a** and subing that value into the equation on the right. Solving for **T**, I get the same answer as you did.

Prix is correct, the masses in the book's answer cancel leaving only *g*, an acceleration, not a force.